# Car parking problem

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

I want to park my car doing similar to the one in the image. But I want to define a curve such that I park the car at once (without going forward, always backward). Suppose that the place that I want to park is 1.5 times longer and 1.2 times wider than my car.Can you model such a curve? [image: Image is taken from wired.com]

Comment: I removed the tag "elliptic curves" and added the tag "Conic sections" instead. "elliptic curves" is an advanced topic in mathematics that I hope I study it someday !

Answer (score 3):

If you could turn all four of your wheels to point left-right, , then parking is trivial -- pull up parallel to the space, turn your wheels, then roll in.  The complexity of parking is that your rear wheels are fixed, and your front wheels don't turn all the way.  This doesn't answer your question, but then again the question does not really model how cars move.  An article about the relevant formula is [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/motoring/news/6784428/Scientists-create-formula-for-perfect-parking.html), and the actual paper is [here](http://personal.rhul.ac.uk/uhah/058/perfect_parking.pdf).

Comment: yes I thought the front wheels, so I am not expecting a perfect model. By the way the link is what exactly I was looking for, thank you very much.

Comment: @newzad, you're welcome.  Happy parking!